# Binding user control to property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I am trying to make custom control and bind that to static field. 
I'm kinda stuck but this is how I would want it to work:

```
<BooleanControl desc="Description" bind = {Binding Save.b}/>
```

Desc would be the description for the checkBox, Save is class that holds the field b which needs to be binded to the control.

I'm making custom control because I also need to be able to make the control by giving description and reference to the field to constructor.

Here's what I have now:

```
public partial class BooleanControl : UserControl
{
    public string desc { set; get; }

    public BooleanControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

But I am not sure if this is the right way to do it, since I am not going to change the description, I just need to set it in designer and by giving the value to constructor.
I am still missing the part where I update Save.b according to the value of checkbox (inside BooleanControl) because I'm not sure what is the right way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a dynamic property of type "yourclass" named Bind and when it is filled do what you want with it. It would look like this:

```
public YourClass Bind
    {
        get { return (YourClass)GetValue(BindProperty); }
        set { SetValue(BindProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Bind.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty BindProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Bind", typeof(YourClass), typeof(UserControl1), new PropertyMetadata(BindModified));

    private static void BindModified(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ((UserControl1)d).AttachEventHandler();
    }

    private void AttachEventHandler()
    {
        //Modify what you want here
    }
```

And you would simply use it as you wanted:

```
<BooleanControl Bind="{Binding Save.b}"/>
```

Comment: What is AttachEventHandler for? Do i need to add something to Save class too? Some tutorials said that I need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged and some didn't even talk about that.

Comment: You can use it to write whatever logic you need. If you need to do calculation or anything else.